# is it possible to change the url name?

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I have one machine on which I am running an application and can be accessed through an URL: http://myapp0:port and on another machine (connected to another internet provider) I have one web page which is accessing the first url: http:myapp0:port. Is it possible to change this URL http://myapp0:port into the http://myapp1.

on httpd.conf I have the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin myapp1.ro
DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/htdocs"
ServerName myapp1.ro
ErrorLog "${SRVROOT}/logs/myapp1.ro.com-error.log"
CustomLog "${SRVROOT}/logs/myapp1.ro-access.log" common
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule "http://myapp0:9999" "http://myapp1.ro"
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following configuration within your VHost, this will redirect all the request to this specific Vhost to http://myapp1.ro.

```
Redirect / http://myapp1.ro
```